# Mumbai - Transaction Underpriced nightmare

Tags: metamask, gas, polygon, smart-contract

I am getting the "transaction underpriced" error on Mumbai almost every time I am sending a transaction no matter if it's from my web app or from Remix IDE...

The only way to pass the transaction is to subsequently manually increase the gas fees parameters in MM (even the "high" priority is not working).

Is it just me, or is the network really busy these weeks ?
Is there anything I should do to solve this ?

```js
{code: -32603, message: `[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{…e":-32000,"message":"transaction underpriced"}}}'`, stack: '{\n  "code": -32603,\n  "message": "[ethjs-query] wh…gaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-2.js:10:55500)'}
```

Comment: there is an RPC function `SuggestGasPrice()` you can call it and get the price you need to use , to avoid this nightmare

Comment: That error usually appear when you are trying to replace a transaction. Perhaps, you have a pending transaction with a low gas price.

Comment: Change the rpc url. That worked for me.